# On proving that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a Euclidean domain.

Tags: eisenstein-integers

To connclude the proof of an Eisenstein integer to be an Euclidean domain I need to show that $N(r)<N(\beta)$ where I have this assumption $|t-p|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $|s-q|\leq\frac{1}{2}$, $r=\beta \phi$ where $\phi=(t-p)+(s-q)\omega$ and $t=\frac{ac+bd-ad}{c^2+d^2-cd}$ and $s=\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2-cd}$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then
$N(r)= N(\beta \phi)$$=N(\beta)N(\phi)$
$=N(\beta)((t-p)^2+(s-q)^2-(t-p)(s-q))\leq N(\beta)(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})
=\frac{3}{4}N(\beta)<N(\beta).$
Am I allowed to compute $N(\phi)$ where $t-p$ and $s-q$ are not surely integers ? If it is not integers then it violates that definition of the norm of Eisenstein integers. Is $t-p$ and $s-q$ are inetegers ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniqueness, units of the Eisenstein Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164656/uniqueness-units-of-the-eisenstein-integers)

Comment: About the point "If it is not integers": the same question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521547/on-the-norm-of-eisenstein-integer/2523611), so see the answers there:"The norm in this case is just multiplying ϕ by its conjugate, which will give you the same formula for rational coefficients since they are invariant under conjugation."